# Distriqt share app values

Tags: share, distriqt

Within the Distriqt Share ANE example app we are shown how determine whether Instagram is installed on Android.

if (Share.service.isApplicationInstalled( "com.instagram.android", "instagram://app" ))

Would anyone know whereabouts I could find the app identifiers for other social networks for both Android and iOS? i.e.

Facebook Android
Facebook iOS
Twitter Android
Twitter iOS
Instagram iOS

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 0):

Checkout their folders on android /mnt or somewhere -- that'll be their reversed domains.